# .net core equivalent to Debugger.Break()

Tags: c#, debugging, .net-core

In `.NET` Core, is there a way for the `C#` code in my exception handler to always break when a debugger is attached, like `Debugger.Break()` in the prior `.NET`?

Comment: try Debugger.Launch();